# The Absolute Position Div inside my table exceeds the table and wrapping div

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, css-tables

I have a calendar I am using which is stretching far outside the container. I have tried changing the overflow to hidden, adding a wrapper div outside the container, switching to relative positioning and more, but still it will not stay inside the parameter of the table. Here is a link to my fiddle... You will note items like the 3 day meeting do not end within the cells, but extend past.

Here is the css portion, the html portion is long and unwieldy since it renders a calendar.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .days.theWeekend {
        background: #333;
    }
    .main {
        width: 1863px;    }
    .month {
        background-color: black;
        font: bold 12px verdana;
        padding: 5px;
        color: white;
    }
    .daysofweek {
        background-color: gray;
        font: bold 12px verdana;
        color: white;
        float: left;
        width: 49px;
        border-right: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .days {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: verdana;
        color: black;
        background-color: #fff;
        float: left;
        width: 49px;
        border-right: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
        height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: visible;
    }
    .days #today {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: red;
    }
    .eventBar {
        /* width: initial !important; */
        height: 18px;
        background-color: red;
        /*          margin: 10px 0 0 2px; */
        position: absolute;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .eventBar > a {   
        color: #fff;
    }

    .eventBarPurple {
        height: 18px;
        background-color: red;
        margin: 10px 0 0 2px;
        position: absolute;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .eventBarPurple > a {   
        color: #fff;
    }
    .eventBar.thisSiteOrigin {
        background: #0022ff;
    }

    span.monthNumber {
        display: block;
    }

    .ms-rte-embedcode.ms-rte-embedwp {
        width: 2000px;
    }

    table.main {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t0zj6e5w/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to add the following css:

```
table#calendar {
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
}

div#tablewrapper {
position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of the `.eventBar` to `100% !important` and height to auto. Then set `positon:relative` for `.days`

```
.days {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: verdana;
    color: black;
    background-color: #fff;
    float: left;
    width: 49px;
    border-right: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
}
.eventBar {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px 0;
    background-color: red;
    /* margin: 10px 0 0 2px; */
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Also make the width of column bit longer so text would not cut off.
Here is example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Sathsara1431/t0zj6e5w/1/). hope this helps you.